# Why do we take picture either from phone or camera?

Tags: logic, theology

I always wonder why do we take pictures? I understand that sometimes we just want to remember the moment and we want to preserve it so that we can enjoy the feeling later.
Looking pictures always make me feel sad, because i can't enjoy that same thing again,I have came across several cases where people start clicking picture of their food, clothes etc but I prefer enjoy the moment up to the brim rather taking out my phone and start clicking pictures.
Is it necessary to take pictures every time?

Comment: Maybe useful: [Susan Sontag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Sontag), [On Photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Photography) (1977).

Comment: CognativeScience.SE may be a better place for questions like these.

Comment: Same reason we drew pictures on cave walls. Image-making seems to be part of the human operating system. And pr0n. http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2013/02/prehistoric_pornography_chinese_carvings_show_explicit_copulation.html. Also, 20 years ago to have a good camera was to be a photo hobbyist or professional. Today everyone's got one in their pocket. That's why everyone runs around clicking on everything. I agree with your point that taking a photo takes you out at the moment. More people should get their heads out of their smartphones in general.

Answer (score 2):

This question is more like "Why does a dog move its tail?" Some people answer that for the obvious reason the tail cannot move the dog!
Then an obvious answer to the question why do we take pictures might be because pictures aren't photographers! When we ask "Why do we seat?" We might get simple answers like "Because we are tired." Or "Because there is a space to do so." The second answer makes more sense-obviously. In the same fashion we can give a multiplicity of answers why do we take pictures or why do we do anything. Descartes posed the statement "Cogito ergo sum" proving his own existence. Kant postulated the Noumenal World, an idea from the Greeks, like the Theory of the Forms. There are indeed deeper questions than to ask about why do we take pictures, etc. The fact that our senses are finite, and that we move around our own definite Phenomenal world, would be enough to convince us that no matter what we do, its is impossible to know for sure what is real and what is not. That is, of what exists and exists not. Only relativism give us our own subjectivity. Indeed seeing is believing. As to why do we take pictures with our camera or phone: "Because we have them and we get happy when we take them." The irony is that no pictures can be taken beyond Phenomena.

Comment: -1 Because your answer is very superficial. You just comment that we get happy when we take them, and many stories, which are not related to the subject; but you stubbornly ignore the most important part of the question namely that Rajat has an aversion against making photographs and even becomes very sad concerning the photographs when looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I take pictures, is not just for me to view them latter.  Having the moments captured, allows me **to share** them with other people,not only around my vicinity, but even across the world!  I can use them to send information, drawings, designs, etc. to anybody anywhere! They provide me an avenue to communicate with people that are not at "arms length" to me, or in the same time zone.
Obviously, if I were to spend **all of my time** just taking pictures, I would not have time to do any of the things I mention above, or any thing else - which would be very stupid!  You can't be taking pictures just for the sake of taking pictures.  **It has to be a means to a (useful) end**!

Comment: -1, because the question was not about taking pictures for a purpose but this senseless photographing anything. When I sat on a wall in the sunshine, Chinese tourist came and said whether I could leave my place, because I disturbed them while taking their ape pictures. This ape like manner of taking pictures is, what is meant here.